# Virus scanning via boot cd for Mac OS (external virus scan)

Tags: macos, mac, anti-virus, bootable-media, virus-removal

There are quite a few virus scanning boot cds/dvds/usb sticks, but I can't find information about which of them do support scanning a Mac OS system.nning 
Does anyone know more about external virus scans on Mac OS systems?

thanks

Comment: Do you suspect a virus present which is managing to avoid your current detection?

Comment: Hey tetsujin - I want to make sure, that this is not possible. And I am curious, whether such CDs exists for MacOS......

Comment: I don't know of any that are touted as 'portable'. Usually they want to install low-level services to monitor activity. I guess if you found one that just ran as an app you could add it to a boot USB, which you can easily make with TechTool ProToGo or Paragon's Hard Disk Manager. Note, Macs don't have optical drives since about 2010, so you might need one of each type, disk/USB [& OS to match] depending on the age of the Mac. If you have 2 Macs, you could boot the one you wanted to test into Target Disk Mode, though that would potentially expose the other machine to any threat.

Comment: I dont mean portable. I mean an external OS for scanning. There are many scanners for Windows, but I have not found any scanner for Mac OS.
I dont care whether its a CD,DVD or USB stick. Usually such tools are offered as CD/DVD-ISO Images, that is why I said CD/DVD

Comment: Either of my suggestions above can make a bootable USB key, to which you can add any software you like. Mac isn't like Windows in that respect, you can reasonably easily boot to a fully-working OS from USB, without needing a separate licence, like for Windows To Go, or requiring unofficial boot code, like BartPE etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some commercial VirusScanner like Sophos https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx
There is also a free and Commercial Version.
Or try to upload one file another to Join Virus dection online site https://virustotal.com.

Comment: Afaik your links is for a Mac OS virus scanner running on the system itself.
I would like to have a bootable media that scannes the Mac OS system externally.
Virustotal is a good recommendation that I already knew about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to this because I feel this is still unsolved and deserves a lot more attention!

How do I scan my Macbook/Mac OS X which does NOT have any CD/DVD drive anymore and the drive (ssd) not exchangeable?

Specifically, I need a way to scan my entire system, WITHOUT booting from it!

Is there any solution where I can simply boot from a bootable USB-stick with a basic OS and an anti virus installed?